# How can I use a HayStack form that contains a ChoiceField within a Context Processor(Django 1.3)?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have a pretty simple Haystack form that looks just like this:

```
class BasicSearchForm(SearchForm):    
    category_choices = Category.objects.all()
    category_tuples = tuple([(c.id, c.name) for c in category_choices])
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=category_tuples, required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(BasicSearchForm, self).search()

        if self.cleaned_data['category']:
            if self.cleaned_data['category'] != "*":
                sqs = sqs.filter(category__id=self.cleaned_data['category'])

        return sqs
```

I then have a context processor just like this:

```
def search_form(request):
    basic_search = BasicSearchForm()
    return { 'basic_search': basic_search }
```

For some reason, creating a new category object (via the Django admin, and saving it) will not update my category tuple used in the ChoiceField of the form **until** I restart Apache.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post, it deals with your situation:

http://blog.e-shell.org/130

> BUT, there is a problem with that.
>   Doing it that way, the list of choices
>   for each field will be generated on
>   startup time (when you launch the
>   django development server or apache or
>   lighttpd or nginx or whatever you are
>   using). That means that if you add a
>   new user to the maintainers group, it
>   will not appear in the maintainer
>   field until you restart your server!
>
> To avoid that, we will need to add the
>   current available choices before using
>   the form, overwriting the default list
>   of choices:

You want to set the choices whenever the form is initiated:

```
class BasicSearchForm(SearchForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BasicSearchForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        category_choices = Category.objects.all()
        category_tuples = tuple([(c.id, c.name) for c in category_choices])
        self.fields['category'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=category_tuples, required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(BasicSearchForm, self).search()

        if self.cleaned_data['category']:
            if self.cleaned_data['category'] != "*":
                sqs = sqs.filter(category__id=self.cleaned_data['category'])

        return sqs
```

Comment: Gah!  I knew it!  I was forgetting to call the super's __init__ so I ended up breaking things (when I tried to define __init__ myself)!  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I hope that works. The post does it another way by setting the choices after the form is created in the view, but i was thinking this should do the same thing. I'll edit the post to follow the blog if this doesn't work like I think. Good Luck

Comment: Worked like a charm, much appreciated.  I was so close earlier, too >_<!