# How to have Model generated Multiple Choices for Django Haystack Search?

Tags: django, forms, search, django-haystack

I've been banging my head against this all night long and before I drop off, perhaps one of you knows something I've overlooked.

**What works:** I'm trying to create a book search engine using Django 1.4 and Haystack 2.0-dev. I've gotten it to search well through 4 books and their pages which I've imported.

**What doesn't:** However, what I'd like to have is the ability for a user to choose which books a person wants to search through via checkboxes in the form. I keep trying things, but no check boxes show up, no books are listed even though I have the 4 in there with titles, etc.

Here is my search/views.py (mainly borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862666/how-can-i-use-a-haystack-form-that-contains-a-choicefield-within-a-context-proce))

```
from django import forms
from haystack.forms import HighlightedModelSearchForm
from books.models import Book, Author

class BasicSearchForm(HighlightedModelSearchForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BasicSearchForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        book_choices = Book.objects.all()
        book_tuples = tuple([(c.id, c.title) for c in book_choices])
        self.fields['book'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=book_tuples, required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(BasicSearchForm, self).search()
        if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['book']:
            if self.cleaned_data['book'] != "*":
                sqs = sqs.filter(book__id=self.cleaned_data['book'])

        return sqs
```

And here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from haystack.views import SearchView, search_view_factory
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet  
from search.views import BasicSearchForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^search/$', 
        SearchView(
        #template='book_search.html',
        form_class = BasicSearchForm
        ), 
    name='haystack_search'
    ),

    url(r'^accounts/login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),

)
```

I've done a lot of searching on this and scoured the docs all night and it is eluded. Maybe someone out there sees something I haven't? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: was this ever resolved or not ? please check the answer if in anyway it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this approach.

```
1) Make a search title field. Each book will have a title. 
2) Create facets for your titles.
3) So when you search for any text, automatically all your books will be listed. 
Now when user clicks the book name in facets he will see results from that book only.
```

What are your comments on this approach ?